# Is it possible to run PowerShell and Active Directory commands from cPython?

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, cpython

I have 2 questions about cPython (but not IronPython):

1. Is it possible to run PowerShell commands from cPython?
2. Is it possible to run Active Directory commands from cPython?

Comment: Probably not directly, however you could shell invoke a PowerShell script with PowerShell.exe -File or a command with PowerShell.exe -Command.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "run commands".

Active directory can be interfaced with via LDAP (with a package like python-ldap) or, if you must, you can always call third party "commands" directly using on of the many process control libs for python (like [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess))

```
In [4]: subprocess.call('hostname')
rafael-imac.h.xxxxx.zzz
Out[4]: 0
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using subprocess.call you can call PowerShell.exe and call a PowerShell script with parameters that you have values for in Python ( as long as they are simple types like strings and numbers ), or specify a command to run as a string. However you'll only be able to process the text of stdout/stderr in Python rather than the objects that PowerShell works with.